# F# interactive development (repl) in IDE (Rider/VSCode) with the enviromnet in docker

Tags: docker, f#, read-eval-print-loop, rider, f#-interactive

I want the IDE to use the environment in the docker container as the default runner for the files. E.g. I have a .fsx file (just prints hello for now) and I want to execute that from the IDE without installing Mono or DotNet6 on my local machine.

An image that is forever running is available and needs to be set as the default executor for the IDE.
[image: menu screenshot]
Pressing the triple vertical dot asks for a file path. I want to set it to use the docker container as the interpreter.

Below is the docker command used to get the container running.

```bash
docker run -d --name f_sharp_repl mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: A Docker container has an isolated filesystem; programs on the host can't directly call programs in an image (or in a running container).  Unless your IDE specifically supports using an interpreter or build tools out of a container, it's likely not possible.

Comment: It looks that VS Code remote is what you need:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview